# imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 5 to be long

Tags: php

I work with PHP on my project, and my friend use this code :

```
function imagecopyresampled($out, $in, $dstX, $dstY, $srcX=0, $srcY=0, $dstW, $dstH,        $srcW, $srcH)
{
    if($this->GD_VERSION==2)
        return imagecopyresampled($out, $in, $dstX, $dstY, $srcX, $srcY, $dstW, $dstH, $srcW, $srcH);
    else
        return imagecopyresized($out, $in, $dstX, $dstY, $srcX, $srcY, $dstW, $dstH, $srcW, $srcH);
}
```

and when I whant to upload an image I receive this error :

> Warning: imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 5 to be long, string
>   given in
>   /home/mbeuser/public_html/nephrogest/includes/common/image/ImageFilter.class.php5
>   on line 917

this is line 917:

```
return imagecopyresampled($out, $in, $dstX, $dstY, $srcX,
                          $srcY, $dstW, $dstH, $srcW, $srcH);
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($srcX);` output?

Comment: put `echo func_get_args();` as the first line of the function so you can see what the function is getting. The 5th argument should be a number, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your function, the 5th and the 6th parameters are strings :

```
function imagecopyresampled($out, $in, $dstX, $dstY, $srcX='', $srcY='', $dstW, $dstH,        $srcW, $srcH)
                                                     ^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^
```

According to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagecopyresampled.php), they should be Integers, so remove the `=''` in those both parameters and it should be fine ! 
If it still doesn't work, check the parameters where you're calling this function. Make them integers like this : `(int) $var;` or use the `intval` function.

Comment: i change this code to :  function imagecopyresampled($out, $in, $dstX, $dstY, $srcX=0, $srcY=0, $dstW, $dstH, $srcW, $srcH)
    {
        if($this->GD_VERSION==2)
            return imagecopyresampled($out, $in, $dstX, $dstY, $srcX, $srcY, $dstW, $dstH, $srcW, $srcH);
        else
            return imagecopyresized($out, $in, $dstX, $dstY, $srcX, $srcY, $dstW, $dstH, $srcW, $srcH);
    } but i have the same problem

Comment: Read the comments on your post : you need to now what's the parameters wich is giving the error. Try `var_dump($srcX);var_dump($srcY);die();` and give us the output.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `=''` that appear in the parameter list of the function itself.

Comment: i remove it but i have the same probleme

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

The errormessage tells you: the function needs the fifth parameter to be an integer (long) value, not a string, like in your case.

Comment: i change it with 0 but i have the same error

Comment: Do you pass a String to your function?